# SwiftUI TextField with dictonary

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have several text fields and I would like to save all entries in a dictonary.

My dictonary:

```
@State var fieldInput: [String: Binding<String>] = [:]
```

My TextField:

```
TextField("Name", text: fieldInput["Name"]!)
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error when I want to access the view with the TextFields.

```
Fatak error: Unexpectedly found nuk while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary is not sequence container, so every entry in it not persistent on change, so you cannot bind to it, so this is not even allowed.

Here is possible approach

```
@State var fieldInput: [String: String] = [:]
@State private var name = ""

..

TextField("Name", text: $name)
   //.onReceive(Just(name)) {      // << iOS 13.+ (needs import Combine)
   .onChange(of: name) {
      fieldInput["Name"] = $0      // << here !!
   }
```

Comment: That looks like a solution :)
Unfortunately, the onChange method is only available from IOS 14 and I would like to program the APP for IOS 13: /

Comment: @CleanMyFloor, added variant that do the same since SwiftUI 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var fieldInput: [String: String] = [:]
    
    @State var value: String = String() {
        didSet {
            fieldInput["Name"] = value
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        TextField("Enter your name here . . .", text: $value)

    }
}
```